# Use Webform for multiple possible inputs

Tags: webforms, forms

I want to create a webform that will replace a excisting excell file
(visitors download a excell file, fill it in and send it back to the company).
Under here a simplified example of the excell file...

[image: the excell file]

As you can see above the visitor can fill in one line or more lines...

I could make a webform for entering one-line (one product), not so difficult.

But the client should be able to fill in more than one demand (if he wants). 
So after putting in one demand, there should be a possibility, to say/click add one more...

Don't know if this possible with only "webform" module, or is there a other module for this.

Any tips, links, video's ,  comments are welcome!

K.

Answer (score 0):

The [Webform Table Element](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_table_element) module will allow you to setup your webform in a tabular format.

But I don't think it allows for unlimited number of lines as an excel sheet would. Still it could be a reasonable (quick) solution for your need.